# Is it possible to use eos as the only backend for web application?

Tags: api, web

If I create a smart contract implementing the logic there and put js/images outside the eos platform (say S3 or else) is it possible to use eos platform to host 100% backend?

As I understand eos platform has RPC protocol, eosjs can be used for calls, it has delayed transactions support and periodic tasks support.

What can be limitations or disadvantages here? Or is that the future of web development (I mean web apps as "web dapps")?

Comment: are you trying to query s3 from a smart contract? you can't do that

Comment: @confused00 let's say I will have frontend served on some S3 bucket and smart contract to be used for business logic without any single mentioning of S3. As I understand it is possible to have 100% backend with periodic tasks and background tasks in eos, or no?

Comment: yup you can have a project similar to [this](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-project-boilerplate-simple). you can have scheduled tasks and you can make more blockchain calls from the front-end with eosjs

Comment: But if you want to use loging , and singnup functionality  that are very tedious to implement and need   lot of space, can increase your cost of Ram and cpu usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes. Examle: a wallet can you only EOS and no backend.
But in reality most probably you will need some backend.